# Instant API and cloud deploy not updating correctly

Tags: cloud-deploy, api, apifunction

I set up an API and cloud deployed it to get the current weather in my city with

```
co=CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{},ResponseForm[QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[=current temperature in new york city,"DegreesCelsius"]],"JSON"]&],Permissions->"Public"]
```

This works perfectly and I'm able to access the output with an http request.

Only problem is that the value returned for temperature seems to be stuck at the value of when I originally deployed the API.

Is the problem maybe just the actual frequency the data is updated on wolfram's side, or do I need to change something in the code?

Thanks!

PS: I'm new no Mathematica and not sure what's the best way to paste my input code here, so just to explain, for the `=current temperature in new york city` I used the natural language processing function in Mathematica.

Update: Without relying on natural language input, the line above can be replaced with the following. Thanks Syed for pointing this out.

```
co=CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{},ResponseForm[QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[AirTemperatureData[Entity["City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}]],"DegreesCelsius"]],"JSON"]&],Permissions->"Public"]
```

Comment: Explore `Delayed` in conjunction with  `CloudDeploy`.

Comment: Thank you @Syed, that looks like exactly what I need. However, it seems like this changed the format of the API json output as well. It used to have a `Value` field, but that is now gone. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think that the value returned from the API is stuck? It's a weather data and will take time to change. Try deploying something that changes instantly like time and see it will work. I don't see any issue with your API. Try: `api = CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{}, ResponseForm[DateString["ISODateTime"], "JSON"]&]]; Lookup[URLExecute[api, "JSON"],"Result"]`

Comment: Try: `AirTemperatureData[
 Entity["City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}]]` if you don't want natural language input.

Comment: @dsingh you're right, I was expecting it to update at a higher frequency but it makes sense that it wouldn't be too fast, thanks!